# Preventing text from moving between pages in Word 2007 or Open Office

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, openoffice

I have been working on revising a novel using pen and paper, and I am fast approaching the point in which I will be making all these revisions to the original document.

In order to more easily compare the changes I am making to the paper copy of my revisions, I would like to prevent any page breaks from occurring whatsoever during the revision process.  Is there any way to force Word or Open Office not to break pages?

There is not any hard page breaks between the current pages of the documents except between chapters, so changing the page size to one large enough to fit any possible revisions in is not an option, unless it is possible to automatically apply hard page breaks to every page and later remove the breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never written a novel, but I have had to deal with this gripe from a variety of users. The best advice I can give is to never rely on a word processor for pagination w/o manual breaks, especially when going between OO and Word.

One nice solution I can think of is to use [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/), it is free and very easy to use as well as powerful. You could make a series of pages and one big text frame that spanned them and then you can edit and move them around on specific pages as needed. Make a seperate file or text frame for each chapter if you wish.

It exports of PDF very nicely, and is a true desktop publishing tool and not a word processor. You'll probably find it well-suited to your needs.

Comment: While I have not had time to fully dive into Scribus, I have had a chance to poke around in it and it does seem that it will indeed suit my needs well.  Thank you very much.